# Google Or-Tools C++ Eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, or-tools

I am trying to use Or-tools C++ on Linux. I have installed them and generated a make-file successfully.
From the command window, I ran the example successfully. Now I want to use it with Eclipse CDT. 
I have  created a new project and done as follows:

- Properties-> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols ->Libraries ->Add

and then has given the path of my '**or-tools**''**lib**' folder.
I am still not able to use or-tools in my project. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to use"? Are you getting unresolved reference errors?

Comment: I have unresolved inclusion issues.

Comment: Oh, you'll need to set the include path too. The library and its header file(s) are different things.

Comment: I have not found any "include" folder in my or-tools directory so in the "includes" option of the project I have given the path of the folder containing files that I want to include. But I am still having the same problem.

Comment: You should open an issue on the issue tracker, please specify which version, how you build it, your platform (linux?), what did you means by install ?